# Why is the name of the "Field line" is "Field line"?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, terminology, history, vector-fields

Faraday-inspired "[Field lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line)" are not always straight.

> 【My question】
>   Why is the name of the "Field line" is "Field line", not "Field curve"?

This may be a question of the English language, but ...　I have a memory that I learned "Line must be straight, and a curled ’line’ is called a curve".

The article of [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) on Wikipedia has the following description.

> "The notion of line or straight line was introduced by ancient mathematicians to represent straight objects (i.e., **having no curvature**) with negligible width and depth."

The article of [curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve)  on Wikipedia has the following description.

> "In mathematics, a curve (also called a curved line in older texts) is an object **similar to a line which does not have to be straight**."

In this sense, I think the technical term, ’line’ has the nuance of "straight" at least in mathematics.

Is the word "field line" natural in physicists' sense?

Comment: A “line of latitude” isn’t straight either.

Comment: If all lines were straight, we would not need the phrase “straight line”.

Comment: @G. Smith Not unless it’s a geodesic! (From a local point of view) ;)

Comment: Right, but only one line of latitude is a geodesic. That’s why I used latitude rather than longitude. Lines of latitude are generally *not* geodesics.

Comment: Certainly, the latitude lines other than the Great Circle course are not the geodesic line(, but it is a straight line on the map). However, these are certainly called lines.

Comment: @G. Smith Oh yeah i know, it was just a cheeky comment from me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line does not have to be straight, that is not part of the definition of the word.